# Previous post id not showing using this code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Trying to get previous post ID with this code but its only showing current post id

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
if(!empty($prev_post)) {

$xx = get_the_ID($prev_post->ID);
$yy = get_the_ID($post->ID);
echo $xx;
echo $yy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it:

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true); 
echo $prev_post->ID;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.